# Deploying CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Locally, I have my site created in a subfolder on my server (ie: 'mysite': 'http://localhost:8888/mysite). When I try to deploy it, I upload the contents of mysite/ to mysite.com/ (getting rid of the sub folder). When I access the site, the CSS files cannot be found (I'm using: echo $this->Html->css(array('style6', 'mainstyle', 'drop-menu'));). If I upload the site WITH the site folder, I have to do a .htaccess redirct, and then all of my links look like: mysite.com/mysite/about. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is an example LINK (what is screwing everything up and linking me to: mysite.com/mysite/about instead of mysite.com/about): <?php echo $this->Html->link('About Us', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'about')); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the path of the images in the CSS file each time I deploy..

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload your whole app folder to the server but point the root for this site to /app/webroot/

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myapp/app/webroot"
    ServerName myapp.com
    ServerAlias myapp.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This would allow me to access http://myapp.com/about

Comment: That should not be necessary at all. The index.php in the root directory should forward to the index.php in the app directory, which should forward to the webroot, which should either serve the static file or route+dipatch to a cake controller.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Cake are you using? Look at some hardcoded configuration in core.php or elsewhere in app/config that explicitely sets mysite as sub-directory.
After uploading there must be some configuration value forcing Cake to behave like this, because it can not be aware of that it was running locally in that directory. Normally such setting is not needed anyway, Cake detects its relative path on the server pretty well.
The other thing I can think of is maybe caching: empty tmp, you might have uploaded a cached version of your views/elements.